# Why Regex returns me Range value?

Tags: ios, regex, swift

I have a String `Add "ABC" here` and I want to extract `ABC` from those string. For this I do:

```
text.rangeOfString("(?<=\")[^\"]+", options: .RegularExpressionSearch)
```

but it returns me

```
Optional(Range(5..<7))
```

How can I extract those text from there?

Comment: What text do you want returned? Please give some examples as the question is a little bit unclear.

Comment: I wrote in my question. For example: I have a text `Add "ABC" here`. And I want to get this at the end `ABC`. So, the text inside of `" "` @Cristik

Comment: I don't understand the problem, as the name clearly suggests and the documentation seconds the method returns a range of string based on the parameters.

Comment: @A-Live yes, but how can I return the text?

Comment: I suggest opening the [documentation of NSString](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/index.html) and looking for any methods that deal with substrings, there's one that accepts range as a parameter and it is as straightforward as the one you are already using.

Comment: `rangeOfString()` returns a range, regardless of whether you use it with the regular expression option or not, so your question title is misleading.

Comment: Since you have not specified if you need one or more matches, I posted a more or less generic solution that finds all matches with capturing groups.

Answer (score 0):

You firstly need to unwrap the resulted range, and call `substringWithRange`. You can do this via [conditional binding](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH5-ID333)

```
let text = "Add \"ABC\""
let range = text.rangeOfString("(?<=\")[^\"]+", options: .RegularExpressionSearch, range: nil, locale: nil)
if let nonNilRange = range {
    print(text.substringWithRange(nonNilRange))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `"([^"]+)"` regex to extract any matches and any captured groups with the following code:

```
func regMatchGroup(regex: String, text: String) -> [[String]] {

do {
    var resultsFinal = [[String]]()
    let regex = try NSRegularExpression(pattern: regex, options: [])
    let nsString = text as NSString
    let results = regex.matchesInString(text,
        options: [], range: NSMakeRange(0, nsString.length))
    for result in results {
        var internalString = [String]()
        for var i = 0; i < result.numberOfRanges; ++i{
            internalString.append(nsString.substringWithRange(result.rangeAtIndex(i)))
        }
        resultsFinal.append(internalString)
    }
    return resultsFinal
   } catch let error as NSError {
       print("invalid regex: \(error.localizedDescription)")
       return [[]]
   }
}
// USAGE:
let string = "Add \"ABC\" \"ABD\""
let matches = regMatchGroup("\"([^\"]+)\"", text: string)
if (matches.count > 0) // If we have matches....
{ 
    print(matches[0][1]) //  Print the first one, Group 1.
}
```

See [SwiftStub demo](http://swiftstub.com/247339049)

Due to error handling added, no crash should occur when no match is found.

Answer (score -2):

The solution is:

```
let regex = myText.rangeOfString("(?<=\")[^\"]+")
myText.substringWithRange(regex, options: .RegularExpressionSearch)!)
```

Comment: Unless I am mistaken, that does not compile. `substringWithRange()` has no "options" parameter.