# swift rss feed parse extract href from content encoded

Tags: regex, swift, parsing, rss, nsregularexpression

I have a regular rss feed that looks like this

```
<content:encoded><![CDATA[<div style="width: 1280px; " class="wp-video"><video class="wp-video-shortcode" id="video-54267-2" width="1280" height="720" preload="metadata" controls="controls"><source type="video/mp4" src="http://www.thestreetlede.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/bJFWyEWkx5Ri.mp4?_=2" /><a href="http://www.thestreetlede.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/bJFWyEWkx5Ri.mp4">http://www.thestreetlede.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/bJFWyEWkx5Ri.mp4</a></video></div>
]]></content:encoded>
```

my goal is to extract the link  "http.." from this `<a href="http://www.thestreetlede.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/bJFWyEWkx5Ri.mp4">`
using a regex in swift however I'm very new to this concept and my code won't extract the video however i got a regex to work for images here is my code
for images:
`let regex = "['\"][^'|^\"]*?(?:png|jpg|jpeg|gif)[^'|^\"]*?['\"]"`

the part i need assistance with (videos) 
`:let regex = "['\"][^'|^\"]*?(?:mp4)[^'|^\"]*?['\"]"`
this returns:[] everytime I'm not sure how to fix the regex
if i figure out my mistake i will update and any help is appreciated

Update

I created this function but it still isn't working does anyone see the problem or could point me in the right direction

```
func getImageURLsFromContent(content: String) -> [String] {
    let regex = "<a\\s+href=\"([^\"]+)\""
    var substr = content
    var result: [String] = []
    while let match = substr.rangeOfString(regex, options: [.RegularExpressionSearch, .CaseInsensitiveSearch]) {
        var matchingString = substr.substringWithRange(match)
        matchingString = matchingString.substringFromIndex(matchingString.startIndex.successor())
        matchingString = matchingString.substringToIndex(matchingString.endIndex.predecessor())

        if matchingString.rangeOfString("http:", options: .CaseInsensitiveSearch) != nil || matchingString.rangeOfString("https://", options: .CaseInsensitiveSearch) != nil {
            result.append(matchingString)
        }
        substr = substr.substringFromIndex(match.startIndex.advancedBy(matchingString.characters.count))
    }
    print(result)
    return result
}
```

Comment: Try `let regex = "<a\\s+href=\"([^\"]+)\""` and access the first range.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I created this method but still can't get it to work

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34589220/3832970). Use like this: `let string = "<a href=\"ssdd\""`, `let matches = regMatchGroup("<a\\s+href=\"([^\"]+)\"", text: string)`, `if (matches.count > 0) {  print(matches[0][1]) }`.